# How to execute TestNG.xml in multiple browsers in parallel with different logins

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, parallel-processing, testng

I want to execute a testng.xml in multiple browsers parallel with different logins. Now I am using `ThreadLocal` concept and using which I can execute the testng.xml in parallel with a single browser(say 5 instances of chrome driver).

I want to do the same with different browsers like IE, firefox, chrome and EDGE. Here is my sample code.

BaseSetup.class:

```
public ThreadLocal<WebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>()
{
    @Override
      protected WebDriver initialValue()
      {
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Firefox")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:/Softwares/Selenium/Drivers/Firefox driver/geckodriver.exe");
            return new FirefoxDriver(getFirefoxOptions());
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Chrome")) {
            return new ChromeDriver(getChromeOptions());
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("InternetExplorer")) {
            return new InternetExplorerDriver(getInternetExplorerOptions());
        } else if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("EDGE")){
            return new EdgeDriver(getEdgeOptions());
        }
    }
};
```

TestNGSuiteRunner.class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    ArrayList<Thread> trarrls = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    Thread object1 = null;
    try
    {
        inputFiles = args[0];
        xmlFile = inputFiles.split(",");

        for(String file : xmlFile)
        {
             object1 = new Thread(new 
             TestNGParallelConfig(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/"+file));
             object1.start();
             trarrls.add(object1);
             Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

        for(Thread indi_thread:trarrls){
            indi_thread.join();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

TestNGParallelConfig.class:

```
public TestNGParallelConfig(String suitXMLUrl,int portNo) throws InterruptedException
{
    xmlString = suitXMLUrl;
    xmlIndex = xmlString.lastIndexOf("/");
    locationName = xmlString.substring(xmlIndex+1);
    folderName = locationName.replace(".xml", "").toUpperCase();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    //BaseSetup.getInstance().proxyPortNo = portAvailability(portNo);
}

@Override
public void run(){
    List<String> testSuites = Lists.newArrayList();
    testSuites.add(xmlString);
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestSuites(testSuites);
    testng.run();
}
```

The main thing is, if an xml is to be ran in 5 different browsers, 5 different users are needed. Since the application is entirely based on Login and Logout.

Kindly help me to achieve this.

Comment: 1. try creating a pool of login users and add them to a data structure called `LinkedBlockingDeque` using `addAll` method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html. 2. every time, a thread is initiated, get the value from `LinkedBlockingDeque` and remove from it, so that the next thread won't pick that up.

Comment: Thanks. But what should I do to run different browser ? above code implements single browsers multiple instances.

Answer (score 0):

Try Selenium Grid, Testng.xml runs on one browser type at a time. Multiple browsers require multiple executions or class level declaration of browsers which restricts a particular set of test cases in a single browser type. If you want to execute all test cases in all browser types then Selenium Grid is the best option.